# How to conf wildfly 20.0.1 to hibernate 5.5 JTA transaction?

Tags: hibernate, wildfly

I have a little problem to build connection/sessionfactory in hibernate 5.5 through out persistence.xml.

My project is a EJB module, it is deploy in a wildfly 20.0.1 and hibernate 5.5.

I got all logs of every entity that is not mapped,

`Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: MyEntity is not mapped`

this is like consecuenses that hibernate dont have sessionFactory build

`Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory`

In persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
           version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/myDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/queries.xml</mapping-file>
......
```

The data source was creating in log wildfly without problems.

Other thing important is that, server(wildfly 20) don't find any namedquery those are declaring in one xml file and it's importing to persistense.xml

The solition that I got was build this ejb module/project in ear project but I would like create just jar file to deploy it alone.

Any help is well-received.

Comment: If you want to use a different Hibernate version in Wildfly you will have to replace the bundled version and adapt the module.xml or add JARs with a different module slot and activate that slot. Either way, you might also have to adapt the wildfly integration. I don't think it is known at this point if Hibernate 5.5 works with the integration that is used for the bundled version 5.3.x